# KDE Plasma 5 switch between windows with arrow keys

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab, kde-plasma-5

I recently upgraded to KDE5. Something that is really annoying is that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does not have proper behavior. Specifically, in KDE4, when I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, then let <kbd>Tab</kbd> go while still pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, I was able to switch between windows using the arrow key and go in forward and reverse order. Now this does not seem possible anymore. I went to K > System Settings > Window Management > Task Switcher and played around with the options, but no configuration seems to be able to bring this behavior back. Furthermore, since I have virtual workspaces and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Arrows to switch between them, whenever I try to add <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Arrow as shortkey in the Task Switcher, it tells me that it will overwrite the global command. There must be a way to avoid this conflict during <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> invocation since it worked perfectly in KDE4. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I also needed this feature very much, my concern was mostly using arrow keys when KDE task switcher is active. so I built a little tool for it called [karrowswitch](https://github.com/nimatrueway/karrowswitch) which emulates (`shift`+) `tab`/`gravy-accent` key when the task switcher is active and arrow keys are pressed. Feel free to try it.

> KArrowSwitch adds support for arrow keys in KDE default
>   alt+tab/grave-accent task switcher. it is very simply implemented, it
>   detects alt+tab/grave-accent (hence an active task-switcher state)
>   then it emulates "tab/grave-accent" key when right/down arrows are
>   pressed, and "shift+tab/grave-accent" for left/up arrows.

Comment: Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually to use Alt + Tab and than arrow keys you have to select a proper visualization effect to Task Switcher on System Settings.

The default effect, Breeze, currently is not supporting the arrow keys anymore, but you can try the effect "Cover Switch" or some other that will work good with arrow keys too.

That would be nice if you could register a bug report on https://bugs.kde.org/ reporting that Breeze effect will not work with arrow keys while other effects are working ok with arrow keys.

I'm working on my first code to kwin and I'm planning to work on some new features and bug correction in future. I would like to work on this one.